# In Laravel 4, How are the merging rulesets implemented?

Tags: php, validation, laravel, package, validationrules

I'm using the [dwightwatson/validating](https://github.com/dwightwatson/validating/tree/0.10) package to create validation rules in the model.

I particularly like the custom rulesets you can create for different routes.

**Model**

```
protected $rulesets = [
        'set_up_all' => [
            'headline' => 'required|max:100',
            'description' => 'required'
        ],
        'set_up_property' => [
            'pets' => 'required'
        ],
        'set_up_room' => [
            'residents_gender' => 'required',
            'residents_smoker' => 'required'
        ],
        'set_up_roommate' => [
            'personal_gender' => 'required',
            'personal_smoker' => 'required'
        ]
    ];
```

**Controller**

```
$post = new Post(Input::all());

if($post->isValid('set_up_all', false)) {
  return 'It passed validation';
} else {
  return 'It failed validation';
}
```

In the above example, it works well in validating against the **set_up_all** ruleset. Now I would like to combine several rulesets and validate against all of them together.

According to the documentation, the package offers a way to [merge rulesets](https://github.com/dwightwatson/validating/tree/0.10#merging-rulesets). I just can't figure out how to integrate the example provided into my current flow.

According to the docs, I need to implement this line:

```
$mergedRules = $post->mergeRulesets('set_up_all', 'set_up_property_room', 'set_up_property');
```

This was my attempt, but it didn't work:

```
if($mergedRules->isValid()) { ...
```

I get the following error:

> Call to a member function isValid() on array

I also tried this, but that didn't work either:

```
if($post->isValid($mergedRules)) { ...
```

I get the following error:

> array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer

Any suggestions on how I would implement the merging rulesets?

Comment: I believe the method is named `mergeRules()` and not `mergeRulesets()`

Comment: When I try mergeRules(), I get the following error: "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::mergeRules()". Why did you think that is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see - `mergeRulesets()` returns an array of rules.

So if you do this - it might work:

```
$post = new Post(Input::all());
$post->setRules($post->mergeRulesets('set_up_all', 'set_up_property_room', 'set_up_property'));
if($post->isValid()) { 
     ///
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've released an update version of the package for Laravel 4.2 (`0.10.7`) which now allows you to pass your rules to the `isValid()` method to validate against them.

```
$post->isValid($mergedRules);
```

The other answers will work, but this syntax is nicer (and won't override the existing rules on the model).